# How to let others developer know what was tried and didn't work?

Tags: design, communication

Let's say a developer is tasked to implement a certain feature in the codebase. That developer tries to implement the feature using Design A (e.g. a certain design pattern). The developer finds out halfway through implementation that while using Design A appears to be an appealing solution at first, it actually introduces more problems than it solves. Therefore, he decides to go ahead and use Design B to implement the feature.

How can this developer communicate to any future developers (including himself) that they should stray away from using Design A in the implementation for this feature? The developer wants to do this in order to prevent another fellow developer from accidentally re-attempting something that was already tried before and found to not be a good solution (this might happen in a code-refactoring session for example).

Comment: A team will want to implement an internal "knowledge base". Commonly, it is implemented as a wiki.

Comment: @rwong: I have seen this suggestion quite often, but I am not a fan of it. It is IMHO a really bad idea to put such design descriptions into a place where they won't get versioned and maintained together with the code.

Comment: The thing is, I have experienced many times someone attempting a solution they know their coworker failed at, and it succeeded the second time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**By writing it down as a comment at a prominent place of the code which realizes "Design B"!**

Which place one chooses depends on the specific situation, whatever feature this is, whatever "Design B" means, how large it is in contrast to the surrounding code base, and how the code base is structured. It may be

- the top of some function,
- the top of a class, or
- a "readme" file of a module, or
- a specific design document,

whatever fits best and whatever kind of documentation the team prefers, and whatever documentation standard the system or organization has.

I would also recommend to find some place where it is hard to become overlooked, for example, during a refactoring session, as you mentioned this. And it should be versioned and maintained together with the code base itself. So it should not be documented exclusively somewhere outside the code, like in a commit message in the VCS, or in an external Wiki, for example.

Self-documenting code is fine, but high-level design decisions always require high-level descriptions, there is no way around it. And comments in code are exactly for this - to document the non-obvious things and reasons behind certain decisions.